# Key Management in Windows Azure

Tags: azure, cryptography

I'm a bit confused about how to store keys (for data encryption) in Windows Azure.

According to the following two links ([#1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee291586.aspx), [#2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/usisvde/archive/2012/03/15/windows-azure-security-best-practices-part-7-tips-tools-coding-best-practices.aspx)), it is recommended to store the keys/key library in the Windows Azure Storage:

> Storing your own key library within the Windows Azure Storage services is a good way to persist some secret information since you can rely on this data being secure in the multi-tenant environment and secured by your own storage keys.

But the "Security Best Practices For Developing Windows Azure Applications" ([#3](http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/3/e/73e4ee93-559f-4d0f-a6fc-7fec5f1542d1/securitybestpracticeswindowsazureapps.docx)) recommends NOT to store any key related material in Windows Azure:

> Also, developers should not upload 
>   the key or any keying material to Windows Azure Storage, regardless of how careful they are about hiding it. If 
>   any computer or storage services were compromised, it could lead to encryption keys being exposed.

What is the best approach to store keys for encryption in Windows Azure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Azure Key vault service that has been released recently might be a perfect fit for the problem. This has been introduced so that keys can be managed in a central place and access can be easily controlled. It also supports HSM-backed service making it very secure.

Here is a artice on [Getting Started with Azure Key Vault](http://www.rahulpnath.com/blog/getting-started-with-azure-key-vault/)

Comment: This really is the best answer for anyone on azure. The only thing to possibly consider is splitting they keys. Keep one half on a local file (not source code checked), and the other in AKV. That might seem like overkill but it's *much* harder to breach a system if you need to traverse multiple services/domains.

Comment: 5 years later I've to mark this answer as the best one. Further reading: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/keep-credentials-out-of-code-introducing-azure-ad-managed-service-identity/

Answer (score 11):

You'll see from my comment in that first link that I agree with your concerns. :)

Azure has no secure way of storing keys other than it's own Certificate Storage. Here is an article on using this method:

[Field Note: Using Certificate-Based Encryption in Windows Azure Applications](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2011/09/07/field-note-using-certificate-based-encryption-in-windows-azure-applications.aspx)

You'll notice I've also commented on that article's shortcomings too, linking to this question:

[Read azure ServiceConfiguration file's certificate section using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11288233/read-azure-serviceconfiguration-files-certificate-section-using-c-sharp)

An example of using Azure's built in certificate storage to encrypt AES keys (avoiding the RSA restrictions on encrypted data length, while keeping the AES key secure) can be found in this project:

[Codeplex: Azure Table Encryption via Attribute](http://azuretableencrypt.codeplex.com)

The `SymmetricKeyHelper` class in the EncryptDecrypt project is of particular interest.

Kudos to @breischl for mentioning it, and for his contributions to the project.

Comment: Thx for your answer, your comment to the first link made me write this question ;) I'll definitly check out those two links you provided.

Comment: @Robar: I've added an appropriate comment to the second article you linked to as well, and linked this discussion in the first. Maybe they'll reconsider their recommendations, but probably not.

Comment: 1. Thank you for the links, they helped a little bit.
2. Good thing you added the link to this question, maybe they will reconsider their recommendations.
3. It's a pity that there is no real support for storing keys or encryption support for blobs.

Comment: The AzureTableEncrypt project uses the certificate store that way. Though it actually uses the certificate to encrypt an AES key, which is then stored in Azure Table Storage. So it's a bit of a hybrid. 

http://azuretableencrypt.codeplex.com/documentation

Comment: @breischl: The double encryption method was exactly what I was considering using (since RSA restricts the length of data you can encode). Very interesting, thanks.

Comment: @Robar: Check out the project breischl mentioned. It seems to cover the method and the implementation of a solution.

Answer (score 2):

For future Googlers - I've implemented the solution that Stuart Pegg describes above, but decoupled from Azure Tables.

See https://www.fasterweb.io/Blog/two-way-encryption-for-azure-web-roles for a writeup, or https://gist.github.com/strommen/20905504949072fe5e16 for just the code.

Answer (score 1):

There’s always a risk. If someone gains access to your storage account using any means (such as using a tool), they may be able to find out your key. So in the end, it is needed to protect the storage account itself from accessed by unauthorized access.

For example, please do not allow a developer to access the production storage account. This includes don’t allow them to access the account using tools. Please protect the storage account key and do not leak any information in any application.

Only storage administrators (and developers who you 100% trust) can have full access to the production storage account. Then you’re safe to store the key in your storage account.

Comment: -1 Your answer directly contradicts the Best Practices document quoted in the question.

Comment: Additionally, from the Microsoft article I linked to in my answer: *"A developer might store the encryption key in Windows Azure storage as a blob, which will be secure as long as the storage key that references the Windows Azure storage is safe; but this is not a best practice, ..."*

Answer (score 1):

I know that this may be a bit late, but if anyone is looking for a quick and easy implementation of encryption for Azure Websites, I've created a  ([Azure.Security](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Security/) and the source code is currently on [GitHub](https://github.com/cmatskas/Azure.Security). The project is loosely based on the [Codeplex: Azure Table Encryption via Attribute](http://azuretableencrypt.codeplex.com/) project but it is a lot more straightforward and easy to use. A blog post will follow shortly with instructions on how to set it up and use it.