# AES Key Storage Azure

Tags: c#, azure, encryption, aes, key-storage

Ive been looking for few weeks now on the best way to store my encryption keys when i host my application within Azure - although ive read many articles/forums etc. im still completely lost and would just like some clarification. Here is a quick overview of my application.

A user will create a group which many people can be invited to and once in a group you can then upload documents to that group so that people can view them, now what i am wanting is for every document which has been uploaded to be encrypted with AES and stored in my database.

but where do i store the IV and key while in Azure? I was thinking about setting up another database within Azure which will only store my IV/Key and maybe the DocumentId to link back to it.

Is that the best way?

My web app will be created in .NET

Comment: possible duplicate of [Key Management in Windows Azure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11428250/key-management-in-windows-azure)

Comment: The way to do this today (2015 and beyond) is Azure KeyVault: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn903625.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a similar goal as keeping sensitive connection string secure - if so, here is a nice blog post series: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlazure/archive/2010/09/09/10059889.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=twitter&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+SiteHome+(Microsoft+%7C+Blog+%7C+MSDN)

Comment: Thanks for that Simon, that will come in handy later down the line - but it doesnt explain how to move forward with my original question, unless im barking up the wrong tree. Would you suggest i use asymmetric encryption to encrpyt my documents instead of symmetric encryption?

Comment: Referencing simon's user name as wasnt sure if he received a notification (not sure if post author meant me as the original question or Simon for his answer) - Im a newbie at SO.

Comment: Sorry for the delay - I am also new to SO - I was merely suggesting how to properly maintain secrets in Azure - the series point to how to keep a secret key (connection string in their case) properly encrypted (using certificates).

Answer (score 0):

Recently there has been Azure key vault service that is launched that would be a perfect fit for this scenario. Key vault is a HSM-backed service for for managing cryptographic keys and secrets.

Here is a small article that I had written on [Getting Started with Azure Key Vault](http://www.rahulpnath.com/blog/getting-started-with-azure-key-vault/)

Comment: You should've flagged this question as a duplicate of the other question that you answered instead of basically having (nearly) identicaly answers.

Comment: I have been looking into using the new Key Vault. I tried to follow the Azure Team blogs to get it up and running with little success. Your blog looks very helpful to implement the new service so i will definitely have a read of it.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Yeah sure, from next time. Missed on that. Thanks for pointing that out :)